# Read spanner data from a table which is simultaneously being written

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I'm copying Spanner data to BigQuery through a Dataflow job. The job is scheduled to run every 15 minutes. The problem is, if the data is read from a Spanner table which is also being written at the same time, some of the records get missed while copying to BigQuery.

I'm using readOnlyTransaction() while reading Spanner data. Is there any other precaution that I must take while doing this activity?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the dataflow job? For example, is it reading the entire table at a specific timestamp every 15 minutes, and writing out all the data?

Comment: It reads the latest data every 15 minutes. The DF job picks up the data having update_date > max(update_date) 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm;ss.SSS' from previous run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to use Cloud Spanner commit timestamps to populate columns like `update_date`. Commit timestamps allow applications to determine the exact ordering of mutations.

Using commit timestamps for `update_date` and specifying an exact timestamp read, the Dataflow job will be able to find all existing records written/committed since the previous run.

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/commit-timestamp

https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/timestamp-bounds

Answer (score 0):

> if the data is read from a Spanner table which is also being written at the same time, some of the records get missed while copying to BigQuery

This is how transactions work. They present a 'snapshot view' of the database at the time the transaction was created, so any rows written *after* this snapshot is taken will not be included.

As [@rose-liu mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53840711/279400), using commit timestamps on your rows, and keeping track of the timestamp when you last exported (available from the [ReadOnlyTransaction object)](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/spanner/ReadOnlyTransaction.html#getReadTimestamp--) will allow you to accurately select 'new/updated rows since last export'